# Creating a Kotlin Native Background Dispatcher for Coroutine

Tags: ios, kotlin, native, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently trying to write a dispatcher for iOS, to run Http requests in the background. My current attempt is the following object:

```
val runCoroutineDispatcher: CoroutineContext = NsQueueDispatcher

object NsQueueDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher(){
    override fun dispatch(
            context: CoroutineContext,
            block: Runnable
    ){
        dispatch_async(
           dispatch_get_global_queue(
                    NSNumber(double = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT.toDouble()).integerValue,
                    0)
        ) {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to use this dispatcher for a coroutine I always get the issue

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared de.ubimax.common.dispatcher.NsGlobalQueueDispatcher.$dispatch$lambda-0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1@8147aca8 from other thread
        at 0   FrontlineClientCommon               0x00000001012d0fec kfun:kotlin.Throwable.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.Throwable + 92
        at 1   FrontlineClientCommon               0x00000001012c9ebc kfun:kotlin.Exception.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.Exception + 88
        at 2   FrontlineClientCommon               0x00000001012c9980 kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.RuntimeException + 88
        at 3   FrontlineClientCommon               0x00000001012f92dc kfun:kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException.<init>(kotlin.String)kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException + 88
        at 4   FrontlineClientCommon               0x00000001012fae84 ThrowIllegalObjectSharingException + 512
        at 5   FrontlineClientCommon               0x000000010185cc9c _ZNK16KRefSharedHolder3refEv + 100
        at 6   FrontlineClientCommon               0x0000000101879144 Kotlin_Interop_unwrapKotlinObjectHolder + 48
        at 7   FrontlineClientCommon               0x00000001017aa184 _knbridge33 + 120
        at 8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bed7fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
        at 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108beebd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
        at 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf12d4 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 872
        at 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108c00160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
        at 12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108c00a88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
        at 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a6160f48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
        at 14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a6163ad4 start_wqthread + 8
```

Sample code:

```
 CoroutineScope(runCoroutineDispatcher).launch {
     println("Hello World")
 }
```

So far I only could find examples with the usage of dispatch_get_main_queue() instead of dispatch_get_global_queue().

Comment: Hello! [This](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/470) is the example you mention? If not, maybe it can help. Also, I think that you're probably violating the [immutability rules](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/IMMUTABILITY.md#immutability-in-kotlinnative) of the Kotlin/Native here.

Comment: Hi. I basically got inspired by this post: https://medium.com/quick-code/kotlin-native-ios-a1a73d7390fe.

My plan was acutally to create one dispatcher for the background tasks. Can you help me out?

Comment: It seems like the only problem comes from [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/462) issue. I mean, have a look at **UPDATE: Currently, coroutines are supported only on the main thread.**